# ki.label = ki.label is null and this not works keyboard

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

ki.label = ki.label is null and this not works keyboard how to set ki.label =???    help me      ki.label =  this.label not work

```
for (Key ki : this.keyboard.getKeys()) {
            switch (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ki.codes[0]))) {
                case Utils.SHIFT_CODE:
                     ki.icon = this.shiftOffDrawable;
                     break;
                 case Utils.KEYCODE_NUMBERS1:
                     ki.label = ki.label;
                     break;
                 case Utils.KEYCODE_NUMBERS:
                     ki.label = ki.label;
                     break;
                 case Utils.KEYCODE_ALPHABETS:
                     ki.label = ki.label;
                     break;
                 case -5:
                     ki.icon = deleteDrawable;
                     ki.repeatable = true;
                     break;
                 case -4:
                     ki.icon = enterDrawable;
                     break;
                 case ValueAnimator.INFINITE:
                     ki.icon = shiftOffDrawable;
                     break;
                 case 32:
                     ki.icon = spaceDrawable;
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
             }
         }
```

Comment: `ki.label = ki.label` assigns the value of a variable to that variable. So basically it does nothing. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Also, please give a complete code example. You need to include a class and a method so that the code can be compiled. Be sure to show the **exact** error message that you get.